# remove leading/trailing white spaces in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

How can I remove leading/trailing white space before/while marshalling in JAXB?

Comment: Remove from what ? The XML, or the String values being marshalled ?

Comment: any String that's being added into xml stream...

Comment: I don't get your question, do you need to now if it's possible or necessary or advised or how it's done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`CollapsedStringAdapter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/CollapsedStringAdapter.html):

```
public class MyClass {

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class) 
   private String field;

}
```

> This adapter removes leading and
>   trailing whitespaces, then truncate
>   any sequnce of tab, CR, LF, and SP by
>   a single whitespace character ' '.

Comment: is there any way to put this on all fields with String data type when generating classes using xjc?

Comment: I tried this solution. But when unmarshalling an XML file, exactly nothing happens, any idea why?